# View lidR LAScatalog Processing Engine Options settings

Tags: r, lidr

Is it possible to view the settings for LAScatalog processing engine options settings in the current working environment? For example, what is the default setting for `opt_chunk_buffer()`?

For example when printing no information is given on the default settings

```r
ctg
#> class       : LAScatalog (v1.2 format 1 and 3)
#> extent      : 195000, 330000, 5432000, 5725000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-67.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
#> area        : 31399.17 km²
#> points      : 204.39 billion points
#> density     : 6.5 points/m²
#> num. files  : 31444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `summary` function gives many informations on the current state of the processing options.

```r
summary(ctg)
#> class       : LAScatalog (v1.2 format 1 and 3)
#> extent      : 195000, 330000, 5432000, 5725000 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-67.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
#> area        : 31399.17 km²
#> points      : 204.39 billion points
#> density     : 6.5 points/m²
#> num. files  : 31444 
#> proc. opt.  : buffer: 30 | chunk: 0
#> input opt.  : select: * | filter: 
#> output opt. : in memory | w2w guaranteed | merging enabled
#> drivers     :
#>  - Raster : format = GTiff  
#>  - LAS : no parameter
#>  - Spatial : overwrite = FALSE  
#>  - SimpleFeature : quiet = TRUE  
#>  - DataFrame : no parameter
```

If you want to get the value for further processing you can call each function individually e.g.

```r
opt_chunk_buffer(ctg)
#> 30
```

You can also access the storage location. There are 4 slots `@processing_options`, `@chunk_options`, `@output_options`, `@input_options`. Each containing a `list` of options (see `?LAScatalog-class`)

```r
ctg@processing_options
#> $progress
#> [1] FALSE
#> 
#> $stop_early
#> [1] TRUE
#> 
#> $wall_to_wall
#> [1] TRUE
```